# Vue.js + Element UI: How to set float attribute?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I've component with a template like the following:

```
<template>
    <el-row>
      <el-form-item label="test" prop="test">
          TEST
      </el-form-item>
    </el-row>
  </el-row>
</template>
```

And I'd like to align its content to the right.

I've tried to add the `float` attriute using the style (and it worked):

```
<el-form-item label="test" prop="test" style="float: right">
```

But I guess if exists a native one, something like:

```
<el-form-item label="test" prop="test" float="right">
```

Can anyone tell me what's the best way to align content to the right with Element-UI / Vue.js, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `float` attribute or prop. The `style` attribute is fine.